# How to use Ubuntu pen drive on Windows?

Tags: usb, drive

I am totally a new user of Ubuntu 14.04.

My problem is that I installed Ubuntu through the USB drive. Now I want to use the pen drive on Windows. I tried to format the pen drive but failed.

Comment: In Ubuntu open an app called (Gnome) Disks, click on the usb stick icon and choose Format. Obviously, you'll have to format it to ntfs or fat in order to use it in Windows. Alternatively, you can do similar operation in Windows too. Open Computer, right-click on usb stick icon and choose Format.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install GParted from Ubuntu Software or via apt-get.
2. Start GParted and select your USB device (example: `/dev/sdc`). Verify selected device size matches the USB device size.
3. Delete any partitions on the USB device.
4. Create a new partition and format as FAT32 or NTFS.
5. Apply changes.